# Audio decoding using ffms2(ffmegsource)

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I'm using ffms2(ffmpegsource) a wrapper around libav to get video and audio frame from a file. 
Video decoding is working fine. However I'm facing some issues with audio decoding.
FFMS2 provide a simple function `FFMS_GetAudio(FFMS_AudioSource *A, void *Buf, int64_t Start, int64_t Count, FFMS_ErrorInfo *ErrorInfo);` api to get the decoded buffer. The decoded data is return in buffer provided by user.

For single channel the data is interpretation is straight forward with data byte starting from first location of user buffer. However when it comes to two channel there are two possibilities the decoded data could be planar or interleaved depending upon sample format return by FFMS_GetAudioProperties. In my case the sample format is always planar which means that decoded data will in two sperate data plane data[0] and data[1]. And this is what is explained by libav/ffmpeg and also by portaudio which consider planar data to be in two separate data plane.

However FFMS_GetAudio just take single buffer from user. So can I assume for planar data
data[0] = buf, data[1] = buf + offset, where offset is half the length of buffer return by FFMS_GetAudio.

FFMS does not provide any good document for this interpretation. It would be great help if some can provide more information on this.

Answer (score 1):

FFMS2 currently does not support outputting planar audio. More recent revisions (post-2.17) automatically interleave planar audio, while older versions from before libav added support for planar audio simply ignore all planes after the first.

Comment: Are you sure about this? The sample format which I'm getting from FFMS_GetAudioProperties is 8. Now as per ffms2 api document the sample format could have value from 0 to 4. It doesn't mention anything about planar format. So I thought that this 8 corresspond to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP(8) as per libav sample format. So does that means that the decoded sample which I'm getting from ffms2 are always interleaved. Please confirm also can you point to some document or code which confirms this.

Comment: After debugging through code, it seems that ffms2 does output planar format as per my assumption in the same one big buffer. And the sample are separated by offset equal to half the buffer. So first half contains channel 1 buffer while second half contains 2 data. I also verified this by just outputting the data audio data from ffms2  to audio device and for 2 channels it sounds like someone is singing inside tin which also means that audio samples are not interleaved.

Comment: However the audio quality for 2 two is noisy and no matter what i try it still remain the same